# Dev tool for Next.js cache on the client?

Tags: next.js, caching, react-query

React Query has this handy dev tool [`react-query-devtools`](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/devtools) to keep track of whether a piece of cached data is fresh, stale, is being fetched, etc., and it even gives you manual control to initiate cache invalidation, refetching, and so on at runtime.

I'm wondering if there's anything of this sort for Next.js's native caching solution. (I did some research on this, but wasn't able to find anything conclusive.)

Just in general, how do you recommend I keep track of the state of my cached data at runtime when in dev mode?

I just feel like installing `react-query-devtools` and hooking it up with my state variables would be a bit of an overkill.

What do you think?